# Synchronize two Emacs Frame statuses

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I usually work on two Emacs Frames, one for coding with gruvbox theme and a second one for org mode under the leuven themes.

The problem is that the two are not synchronized very well.

For example, the clocked todos in org's Emacs will not be displayed on the coding Emacs?

Is it possible to solve the problem?

The details of my machine

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:        18.10
Codename:       cosmic
```

Comment: I don't understand the question / your set-up.  Please define *exactly* what you mean by "two Emacsen".  Are they different versions?  Do they share a common config?  Are they looking at the same org files?  Provide details.  (The only details you've provided is your OS, which I suspect is actually irrelevant in this case.)

Comment: sorry, it was get edited by the community friends and I thought "emacsen" is more professional, I  changed it to emacs frame. @phils

Comment: Still a bit confusing -- "two frames" would usually suggest you had started a single instance of Emacs and opened a second frame in it.  Here I *think* you are saying you have run two independent instance of Emacs (and have a single frame for each) ?

Comment: It might be worth looking into using `auto-revert-mode` in your org buffers.  I'm unsure whether that's useful or not.  If you could add a recipe to reproduce/demonstrate the problem, that would definitely help to clarify the question.

Comment: I know the answer now, ` emacs --daemon` and then run other emacs frames. @phils